# Why is my indoor lime tree growing fruit without pollination?

Tags: fruit-trees, citrus, pollination

I'm growing a lime tree indoors. It's about 7 or 8 years old now and finally producing some flowers and also fruit. I just read a home guide from [SFGate](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/lime-tree-need-pollinated-59016.html) that manual pollination is required to grow fruit, however I didn't do any on my tree, and there are a few flowers that seem to be growing little, tiny limes from the centre of the flower. Do you have any idea why this may be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sfgate and the other content mills are crap. Lots of times articles are written by people with little or no experience other than the ability to paraphrase. I remember reading a lawn care article written by a hair stylist. Most of the time they just copy stuff from other sources and reword them.

This page from a dwarf citrus grower indicates you [don't need to pollinate indoor citrus trees](https://www.fourwindsgrowers.com/solver/pollination.html) as they're self pollinating. I'd trust them over some "farm boy"/suspense writer.